# Stop C++ Service Application

Tags: c++, service, warnings

I created a C++ Service Application and installed the service when I try to stop the service a warning is shown.

The Service contains just one implemented method that is:

```
void __fastcall TService1::ServiceExecute(TService *Sender)
{
    bool a = true;
    while(a){
       sleep(5);
       writeLog("test \n");
    }
}
```

How can I stop the service by brute force, so does not show the warning?

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to stop a service program is to implement a [Service Control Handler Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which can respond to the `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` control code. Usually the handler will set a stop event, which will cause the [ServiceMain](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) loop to exit (example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687413%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

If you used a template to generate your service application, you may already have the stub interfaces implemented to do this.  If not, you would need to implement them.

Implementing a native Windows Service is not trivial, and cannot be done with just a single executable method.  A service application must implement the interfaces used by the Service Control Manager (SCM), such as the [Service Entry Point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685477%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [Service ServiceMain Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and a [Service Control Handler Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685149%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It must also [report status and state changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee126211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to the SCM. See a complete examples from Microsoft [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb540476%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CppWindowsService-cacf4948).

MSDN reading reference: [Service Programs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If you don't want to implement all of the required SCM interfaces and logic, there are options available from both Microsoft and third parties to run any executable as a service.  See Microsoft's [srvany.exe method](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890/en-us), or Iain Patterson's [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/download/?page=download) for example.